# Upgrade CentOS (RedHat) 5.4 to 6

Tags: linux, centos, upgrade, redhat

I have a server with a CentOS (RedHat) 5.4, I would like upgrade to CentOS 6.

How I can upgrade and what is the upgrade commands ?

Comment: CentOS 5 is based on Fedora 6. CentOS 6 on Fedora 12. Huge differencies. Therefore no possibility for an upgrade ... See the documentation in the below answer ... @cyclops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

centos only support 6 to 7 upgrades.

but if you want to upgrade 5 to 6 then you can checkout the [redhat documentation](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/21964) and [centos documentation](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/MigrationGuide/MigratingFiveToSix)  (the methods in this documentation are supported by the CentOS Project)